# using Zurb Foundation with wordpress no conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation-5

I am currently developing a custom theme using foundation and _s I had a few questions.I have followed this tutorial [Here](http://wordpress.tv/2014/06/11/steve-zehngut-build-a-wordpress-theme-with-foundation-and-underscores/) enqued all my script etc and now its working.

My only concern is the jquery, on some forums is says that i have to deregister the jquery and then register another one etc. On some forums its says that i have to use a non conflict mode while others tell me just to enque it and thats it. what is proper practice in this case? I am not looking for a temporary solution I would like this theme to update without issue or breaking in the future.

In the case of using the non conflict method. I have created a file named foundation.js and have enqued it in the functions.php file with this code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

Is this the right method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the `noConflict()` mode. In  `noConflict()` mode, the global `$` shortcut for jQuery is not available. So in `foundation.js` you can just use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery(document).foundation();
});
```

[check this link from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery(document).foundation();
});` If i simply place this in the foundation.js i am gaunranteed that I will not have problems in the future with updates of wordpress etc?

Comment: I have no idea what the future updates of WP will entail :) But this is what I've done after following the same tutorial you did, and then scrapped and developed my own.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is sketchy, but this should be the correct way, at least it works for me:

In functions.php:

```
function my_enqueue_foundation() {
    wp_register_script('foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js','','1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('foundation');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_foundation' );
```

Then initialize foundation in footer.php

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>


<script> jQuery(document).foundation(); </script>
```

Comment: `<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation.min.js"></script>` is this a necessary procedure? pardon my ignorance but what does that do exactly'

Comment: @steamfunk. Sorry, that was incorrect, I checked in an old template. I corrected my answer above.

Comment: also see [http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)

Comment: what is the importance of initializing foundation in the footer as opposed to in a separate .js file?

Comment: This is done to comply with Zurb's recommendation to "initialize Foundation at the end of the page `<body>`." To achieve a similar effect, instead of editing `footer.php`, you could hook into `wp_footer` (instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`) to add the init script and use a ridiculously high value for the priority parameter, e.g. `99999` or `( PHP_INT_MAX - 1 )`.

Comment: Hello Diggy, from what I understand this is not the conventional method or recommended one according to the people at wordpress. what is the importance of hooking it in the footer is that to speed up page load times? and is it incorrect to enque the script?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the tutorial you linked to ([github](https://github.com/stevezehngut/ocwc2014-foundation)) you're all set. In the theme's `functions.php` file foundation JS and an init script are enqueued:

```
function awesome_theme_scripts(){
    // scripts here ...
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/foundation/js/foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-init-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/foundation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1', true );
    // more scripts...
}
```

The latter contains the `noConflict` code and initializes Foundation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```